# How to find $count in mongoose for same group?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

how to retrieve count for quantity and price in for same group in mongoose

```
db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Need more clarification on what you are trying to achieve? What is same group??

Comment: Which format???

Comment: i am trying to retrieve count for two match conditions for the same group

Comment: Please share input data and output at json editor online

Comment: Show your model and full query you have tried so far. Don't add your code in comment section. You can edit  you question anytime, so edit the question with your model and query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $facet to get count of multiple group in single query. check the below query is helpful to your requirement.

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
{ "$facet": {
"quantity": [
{ "$match" : { "quantity": { "$lt": 20 }}},
{ "$count": "Total" },
],
"price": [
{ "$match" : {"price": { "$eq": 10 }}},
{ "$count": "Released" }
]
}},
{ "$project": {
"quantity": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$quantity.Total", 0] },
"price": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$price.Released", 0] }
}}
])
```